# How do I create an bootable win 7 usb in ubuntu?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, usb, windows-7

Iḿ Using an EEE pc and dropped my win device. I dont have a disk drive as y'all may know..

I just want to reload my windows 7 from a bootable usb, which I wanna create on ubuntu 13.04.

After that I wanna Reinstall Ubuntu next to win7.

Iḿ not that kinda hardware person who fixes it in a moment. So if you guys could explain it easily and usuable, you will help me a lot.

Thanks a Lot From Holland

Answer (score 2):

First, download WINusb by running these commands in the terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

after the installation, run winUSB and specify the *.iso* image you want to use in creating your bootable flash drive

[image: WinUSB screenshot]

Comment: Great comment, is there a posibility to keep this ubuntu on HD r do I need to back up and reinstall later?

Comment: You can keep it on HD, yes

Comment: Care with this software: at the installation it messed up my local grub, making my machine unbootable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNetbootin. Select the Windows 7 iso and create windows 7 bootable pen drive.

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: can i install it next to ubuntu or do i need to backup everything before instal from boot?

Comment: when you install windows 7 it will re-write the grub. so the best solution is to first install windows create partition for ubuntu and then install ubuntu.

Comment: do i make one with nortion partition magic, or uld it be fixxed in the boot menu?