# How can I make a non-bootable ISO file bootable?

Tags: iso

I have an ISO file I want to use to install Windows 7 in VirtualBox. The problem is this file is not bootable. Is there any command line tool to make a non-bootable ISO file bootable?

**Update**

The ISO file is a Windows 7 installation CD/DVD. I created a new virtual machine and attached the ISO file to the corresponding virtual CD/DVD reader device. I'm pretty sure I'm doing this step right because it worked just fine with another ISO file I have.

When I run the machine with this ISO file attached I see the "no bootable medium found" error.

I suspect the cause of the problem is that the ISO file I'm interested in is not bootable. When I run the `file` UNIX command to see the type of the file, this is the output:

```
file windows7.iso 
windows7.iso: ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'CDROM'
```

However, if I run the same command agains the "good" ISO file it says "(bootable)":

```
file W7X64.OEM.ESD.en-US.Oct2016.iso 
W7X64.OEM.ESD.en-US.Oct2016.iso: ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'W7X64.OEM.ESD.EN-US.OCT2016' (bootable)
```

Comment: Please try this links: https://askubuntu.com/questions/847834/how-to-create-bootable-windows-7-usb-on-ubuntu-16-04, and https://askubuntu.com/questions/409161/how-do-i-create-an-bootable-win-7-usb-in-ubuntu

Comment: I never made one I just downloaded the `.ISO` file from Windows and used it in my VM

Comment: Have you checked that the iso file was downloaded correctly? A good Windows 7 iso file works directly in VirtualBox. It needs no special treatment. It is possible, but maybe a bit difficult to find a listed checksum (for example md5sum) for your iso file. An alternative is to find another version of the Windows 7 iso file, that has a matching checksum, and download it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You may use the IMGBURN software (You need a windows for that). The software is free but will try to install some side softwares if you don't disable the options.
- From a bootable win7 CD, copy the file etfsboot.com somewhere
- From ImgBurn choose : Create CD from files and for the sources files, choose everything from your non-bootable iso. Selecting the root folder of the mounted iso shall do the job
- Choose a destination file on your hard disk, eg : new.iso
- On the Advanced Tab, choose Bootable disc :
- For the bootimage, choose the file etfsboot.com you saved before

  - For Load Segment, type : 07C0
  - For Sectors to load, type : 8
- Finally click on the build button and Yes on each dialog appearing (about 3 of them)

Your new iso should be good to boot.

Comment: I just tried this and it works! The file command now says the ISO file is bootable and it boots when I run the virtual machine. Is currently installing and it's going well so far. Thanks!

Comment: Good :-) Happy it was useful :-)

Answer (score 1):

All virtualization solutions nowadays attempt to use **hardware assisted** virtualization, instead of **software emulation solutions** (binary translation). One of those hardware virtualization technologies is Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x). Although AMD supports its own virtualization technology (AMD-V), the basic processor virtualization extensions are named after Intel's solution. I would not like to go any further on virtualization theory and such, if you would like to read, this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization) is highly informational.

## How to enable VT-x

There are two configurations you should perform if you would like to enable hardware assisted virtualization. Those are:

- [First of all, make sure that you have enabled Virtualization extensions in your hardware](https://www.google.gr/search?q=how%20to%20enable%20virtualization%20in%20bios&sugexp=chrome,mod=10&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).
- After you have done so, enable VT-x in the virtual machine configurations. To do so: right-click on a virtual machine (Windows 7 in your case) in the VirtualBox user interface -> *Settings* -> *System* -> *Acceleration* tab -> *Enable VT-x/AMD-V*

  [image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't know all this. However, it seems is not related to the problem I'm having. Virtualization extensions were already enabled in my computer and VT-X was already enabled in the virtual machine.

Comment: This answer has exactly nil to do with making a windows 7 cd bootable.